# Парсинг HTML файла с помощью BeautifulSoup в DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, pandas, beautiful-soup

Имеется файл вида:

```
<TD class="c1">111-1111</TD>
<TD class="c2">AA1111-1111</TD>
<TD class="c3">NAME1</TD>
<TD class="c4"><INPUT type="text" id="F1" readonly="readonly" value=" .368"></TD>
<TD class="c5"><INPUT type="text" id="Q1" readonly="readonly" value=""></TD>
</TR>
<TR class="r1">
<TD class="c1">222-2222</TD>
<TD class="c2">BB2222-2222</TD>
<TD class="c3">NAME2</TD>
<TD class="c4"><INPUT type="text" id="F2" readonly="readonly" value=" 1.28"></TD>
<TD class="c5"><INPUT type="text" id="Q2" readonly="readonly" value=""></TD>
</TR>
```

С него мне нужна информация в виде pandas.DataFreme которая лежит в блоках TD class="c1", TD class="c2",TD class="c3" и значение value= в TD class="c4".
Что бы ее получить я делаю следующее:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
description = [element.text for element in soup.find_all(class_="c3")]
component = [element.text for element in soup.find_all(class_="c1")]
code = [element.text for element in soup.find_all(class_="c2")]
val = re.findall(r'value="(.*?)"', html)
value = [value for value in val if value != '']
value.insert(0, 'Value')

data = []
for a, b, c, in zip(component ,description,value):
    data.append([a, b, c,])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cod','desc','val'])
```

Код работает, если есть предложения по его улучшению (а я уверен что этот код можно улучшить :) ), буду рад выслушать!!!
Собственно вопрос, как мне значение value= которое у меня сейчас  .368 привести к числовому значению вида 0,368 ?
Буду благодарен за любую информацию !

Comment: У вас вопрос в том, как строку преобразовать в число? Очень странно, что подобные трудности могут возникнуть одновременно с использованием `pandas`.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе валидный / полноценный HTML? Присутствует ли в вашем настоящем HTML тег `<table>`?

Comment: mkkik, не совсем строку преобразовать в число . У меня есть строка вида ".368" (точка три шесть восемь).Если есть такие значения в датафрейме мне нужно их преобразовать в 0,368. Грубо говоря добавить 0 перед точкой если перед точкой ничего нету . Не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос. Надеюсь немного разъяснил.

Comment: Т.е. вопрос только о форматировании вывода?

Comment: MaxU,  ссылка на файл. Да тег <table> там есть http://www.filedropper.com/conctextncss0907r50b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path

def get_vals(soup, filt="[class='c4']"):
    ret = [x.input.attrs["value"].strip()
           for x in soup.select(f"td{filt}")[1:]]
    return pd.to_numeric(ret, errors="coerce")

url = r"C:\download\CONCTEXT_NCS_S0907R50B.htm"

soup =  BeautifulSoup(Path(url).read_text(encoding="utf-8"), 'lxml')

df = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]
df["Recipe Qty"] = get_vals(soup, filt="[class='c4']")
```

**результат:**

```
In [123]: df
Out[123]:
  Component     S-W Code                  Description  Recipe Qty  Required Quantity
0  241-2905  TZ4103-3905                   BLUE FTALO       0.368                NaN
1  241-6909  TZ4103-2909                    OXYDE RED       1.280                NaN
2  241-7906  TZ4103-3406                 RED BORDEAUX       1.120                NaN
3   X80LC-G          NaN  WHITE TEXTURED TOP COAT (*)     997.232                NaN

In [124]: df.dtypes
Out[124]:
Component             object
S-W Code              object
Description           object
Recipe Qty           float64
Required Quantity    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: MaxU, Спасибо !!! То что мне нужно.